# 1993 nissan hardbody headlight prob

Tags: nissan, headlight, pick-up

My 1993 Nisssan hardbody pickup has headlight problem.  Low beam works on one side and when i switch to high beams, the other side light works.  I put in two new sealed beam lamps and same problem..  Is there a module somewhere that controls this?  I had a light switch replaced last year so doubt that it is the high/low switch..

Comment: A computer controlled module? I doubt it. You're probably going to have to check and trace wiring from the bulbs to the switch. You'll probably find a broken wire somewhere.

Comment: Specifically the grounds - often when you have a "switching sides" phenomenon the cause is a different path to ground created by adding more "bulbs" to the circuit, causing visible (but incorrect) operation.